# Does Mac OS X support WPF?

Tags: wpf

I've made an WPF application, and I wanted to know if Mac OS X supports it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight WPF apps can work on Mac, but otherwise you'll need to use Parallels or some other virtual machine to run a copy of Windows.  (I doubt Mono has come far enough to run WPF, but I don't know.)

Comment: There's no current plans for Mono to support WPF. http://www.mono-project.com/WPF